# Apply if else function over list of dfs

Tags: r

I guess this is a fairly easy one, but I cannot sort it out on my own.

I have the following list of dfs:

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1=c(1,2,3), col2= c(4,3,6))
df2 <- data.frame(col1=c(5,2,7), col2= c(1,4,8))
df3 <- data.frame(col1=c(4,9,9), col2= c(7,6,4))
list.of.dfs <- list(df1,df2,df3)
```

Now, I want to apply this if-else command on my list of dfs:

```
for (i in 1:length(list.of.dfs)) {
  if (list.of.dfs[[i]]$col2 >= 7) {
    list.of.dfs[[i]]$newcol <- "high"
  } else if (list.of.dfs[[i]]$col2 >= 5) {
    list.of.dfs[[i]]$newcol <- "medium"
  } else if (list.of.dfs[[i]]$col2 < 5) {
    list.of.dfs[[i]]$newcol <- "low"
  }
}
```

I want a new column for each row of my dfs in my list filled with one of the three expressions from my if-else function.

However, it seems like my code only considers the first row in each iteration:

```
> list.of.dfs[[1]]
  col1 col2 newcol
1    1    4    low
2    2    3    low
3    3    6    low
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use `tidyverse`. I created a custom function inside of `purrr::map` so that I could iterate over each dataframe in the list.  I used `case_when` to assign the values in the new values in `newcol`.

```
library(tidyverse)

map(list.of.dfs, function(x)
  x %>%
    mutate(newcol = case_when(
      col2 >= 7 ~ "high",
      between(col2, 5, 6) ~ "medium",
      col2 < 5 ~ "low"
    )))
```

Or another way to write it:

```
map(list.of.dfs, ~ mutate(., newcol = case_when(
  col2 >= 7 ~ "high",
  between(col2, 5, 6) ~ "medium",
  col2 < 5 ~ "low"
)))
```

**Output**

```
[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 × 3
# Rowwise: 
   col1  col2 newcol
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr> 
1     1     4 low   
2     2     3 low   
3     3     6 medium

[[2]]
# A tibble: 3 × 3
# Rowwise: 
   col1  col2 newcol
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr> 
1     5     1 low   
2     2     4 low   
3     7     8 high  

[[3]]
# A tibble: 3 × 3
# Rowwise: 
   col1  col2 newcol
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr> 
1     4     7 high  
2     9     6 medium
3     9     4 low
```

Another option is to use `data.table` with `map`:

```
library(purrr)
library(data.table)

map(list.of.dfs, ~ setDT(.)[, newcol := fcase(
  col2 < 5L, "low",
  col2 >= 7L, "high",
  col2 >=5 & col2 < 7, "medium" 
)])
```

**Benchmark**

It looks like in this case; `data.table` is generally the fastest.

[image]

```
bm <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  maydin_baseR = {for(i in 1:length(list.of.dfs1)) {
    x <- list.of.dfs1[[i]]
    list.of.dfs1[[i]][,"newcol"] <- ifelse(x[,"col2"]>=7,"high",
                                          ifelse(x[,"col2"]>=5,"medium","low")
    )
  }},
  arjunsiva = {rating <- function(r){
    if (r[2] >= 7){
      return("high")
    } else if (r[2] < 5){
      return("low")
    } else {
      return("medium")
    }
  }
  rate.df <- function(df){
    newcol <- apply(df, 1, rating)
    cbind(df, newcol=newcol)
  }
  list.of.dfs2 <- lapply(list.of.dfs2, rate.df)},
  TarJae = {list.of.dfs3 %>% 
    map(~ mutate(., newcol = cut(col2, breaks = c(0, 4, 6, Inf),
                                 labels = c("low", "medium", "high")
    )))},
  andrew_data.table = {map(list.of.dfs4, ~ setDT(.)[, newcol := fcase(
    col2 < 5L, "low",
    col2 >= 7L, "high",
    col2 >=5 & col2 < 7, "medium" 
  )])},
  andrew_tidyverse = {map(list.of.dfs3, ~ mutate(., newcol = case_when(
    col2 >= 7 ~ "high",
    between(col2, 5, 6) ~ "medium",
    col2 < 5 ~ "low"
  )))},
  times = 1000
)
autoplot(bm)
```

Comment: The results without the `rowwise` should be the same, no?

Comment: @DonaldSeinen That's correct; it's not needed in this case. I removed it. Thanks.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant. Thank you very much for these comprehensive solutions.

Answer (score 2):

By following your approach with `Base R`,

```
for(i in 1:length(list.of.dfs)) {
    x <- list.of.dfs[[i]]
    list.of.dfs[[i]][,"newcol"] <- ifelse(x[,"col2"]>=7,"high",
        ifelse(x[,"col2"]>=5,"medium","low")
    )
}
```

gives,

```
[[1]]
  col1 col2 newcol
1    1    4    low
2    2    3    low
3    3    6 medium

[[2]]
  col1 col2 newcol
1    5    1    low
2    2    4    low
3    7    8   high

[[3]]
  col1 col2 newcol
1    4    7   high
2    9    6 medium
3    9    4    low
```

Answer (score 1):

In,
 `if (list.of.dfs[[i]]$col2 >= 7) {`
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used, i.e, `list.of.dfs[[i]]` returns a boolean vector like `[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE` which indicates whether a specific row satisfies the condition or not. So R takes the first value in the vector,(here it is FALSE) and checks the next else if condition. Finally for the case of col2 < 5, the condition is satisfied and assigns the respective value ("low" in your code) to **all the rows** in list.of.dfs[[i]] because you are not addressing each row separately.

You can use two functions - one to check the *col2* value and another wrapper function to apply the first function over the list of dataframes

```
rating <- function(r){
  if (r[2] >= 7){
    return("high")
  } else if (r[2] < 5){
    return("low")
  } else {
    return("medium")
  }
}

rate.df <- function(df){
  newcol <- apply(df, 1, rating)
  cbind(df, newcol=newcol)
}

list.of.dfs <- lapply(list.of.dfs, rate.df)
```

This produces an output:

```
[[1]]
  col1 col2 newcol
1    1    4    low
2    2    3    low
3    3    6 medium

[[2]]
  col1 col2 newcol
1    5    1    low
2    2    4    low
3    7    8   high

[[3]]
  col1 col2 newcol
1    4    7   high
2    9    6 medium
3    9    4    low
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `cut` and then iterate with `map` from `purrr` package over each list element:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

list.of.dfs %>% 
  map(~ mutate(., newcol = cut(col2, breaks = c(0, 4, 6, Inf),
                               labels = c("low", "medium", "high")
                               )))
```

```
[[1]]
  col1 col2 newcol
1    1    4    low
2    2    3    low
3    3    6 medium

[[2]]
  col1 col2 newcol
1    5    1    low
2    2    4    low
3    7    8   high

[[3]]
  col1 col2 newcol
1    4    7   high
2    9    6 medium
3    9    4    low
```